# Npm.require can't find node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have been trying to use the `Npm.require` to get the `ldapjs` module and use it for client authentication, however I am getting the following message.

```
 var ldap = Npm.require('ldapjs');

 Error: Cannot find module 'ldapjs'
```

Isn't the `require` supposed to download the package from the npm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the best way to use NPM packages in Meteor is [this npm smart package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm). The instructions on how to use it are pretty clear there. Basically, you do three things:

1) Install npm:

```
mrt add npm
```

2) Create `packages.json` file with list of required packages:

```
{
    "ldapjs": "0.6.3"
}
```

3) Use the package via **Meteor.require:**

```
var ldapjs = Meteor.require('ldapjs');
```

Comment: Nice answer! I am trying it right now, however MRT is taking forever... :(

Comment: I am behind a proxy so in the end I had to use: `npm install -g meteor-npm`        `meteor-npm `

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not. **Meteor** will only download a node module as long as it is declared within a smart package, with `Npm.depends({...})` directive. If your code is not a part of some smart package, then you'll need to install the node module manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things to use npm modules in Meteor packages:

1. Npm.depends - specify the modules you want to use, with versions. Meteor's build system will download the package and manage its dependencies
2. Npm.require - pull in a module, making it available in the current scope

Note that you need to write a package to use an npm module.  You'll probably want to read through the Meteor docs [on packages](http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages).

For an example, check out the [logging](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/248139c2bcd2e90134e7b1b76e8c305aafa5ec35/packages/logging) package in Meteor.  Its package.js specifies a depency on the npm module cli-color, and its logging.js file requires and uses the module.

Answer (score 0):

## node modules in the main application

What if you want to use **npm** from the main application? And what if you don't want to install node modules manually (a maintenance headache)?

This is possible with a workaround. Create a shim smart package to provide the node modules for the main application. Export the modules to the main application.

### The exact steps

**1.** Create a directory `npm-shim` outside your Meteor application. We will use it in step 3.

**2.** Add these two files to it:

File `package.js`

```
// npm dependencies are only available for packages. If you have npm 
// dependencies for the main application, you need this workaround:
// Create a shim package to provide the npm dependencies to the main app.

Package.describe({
    summary: "Meteor main application npm dependencies"
});

Npm.depends({
    colors: '0.6.2', 
    // Add more modules as needed.
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
    api.export("NpmShim"); // Omit this for versions before 0.6.5
    api.add_files("npm.js", "server");
});
```

File `npm.js`

```
NpmShim = {};
NpmShim.colors = Npm.require('colors');
// Add more modules as needed.
```

**3.** Edit smart.json and add this line:

```
"npm-shim": { "path": <path to the directory created in step 1> },
```

**4.** Execute `mrt update` then `meteor add npm-shim`.

### The result of this workaround

Node modules can be used from the Meteor main application without the need to manually install them. Use `NpmShim.colors` instead of `Npm.require('colors')`.

If you need more modules, you have to add them to `package.js` and `npm.js` (see comment `// Add more modules as needed`).